# Is it possible to appeal a Facebook 'profile report' decision?

Tags: facebook

I have reported a Facebook profile (a "profile", not a "page") as "Represents a business or organisation" which is (I believe) against Facebook's ToS. The profile in question has no 'personal' content on its timeline, it's purely promotion for that business. The name used for the profile is that business' name. The cover photo and profile picture are pictures of the shop-front.

I reported it, Facebook said they followed up on the report but found it did not violate community standards and left it as-is.

I now want to either provide them with more info, or appeal the decision, because whoever reviewed the report was (afaict) wrong to decide no action was required. I considered just reporting it over and over until it's acted upon but:

1. That seems like a waste of time
2. I am concerned that there might exist some kind of "crying wolf" mechanism built into the report profile system. If it exists, it could harm me if I repeatedly report a profile for it to be repeatedly found non-infringing.

By way of background - I have friends who ran profile-as-a-business-page profiles and in the past they have been forced into converting their "friend profiles" into "like pages". So - I know that it can happen, unless Facebook have changed their ToS about profiles-where-you-should-use-a-page in the intervening time.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone but Facebook is going to be able to answer this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to appeal a decision.
I've reported dozens of personal profiles which represent business entities. Many of which are closed stating they don't violate community guidelines.

> People connect on Facebook using their authentic identities. When people stand behind their opinions and actions with their authentic name and reputation, our community is more accountable. If we discover that you have multiple personal profiles, we may ask you to close the additional profiles. We also remove any profiles that impersonate other people.
>
> If you want to create a presence on Facebook for your pet, organization, favorite movie, games character, or another purpose, please create a Page instead of a Facebook Profile. Pages can help you conduct business, reach out to fans, or promote a cause you care about.

It seems that it isn't something Facebook wants to deal with on a case by case basis.

Answer (score -1):

I heard, that about 10 reports is needed. I lost my personal account lately because of false reports, so this is truly sarcastic - misusers is untouchable, honest ones got their accounts closed. No one indeed would not bother to check even after you complaint. But you have chance, if they answer (this automatic answer, that everything is perfect!), you can rate this answer, choose :( face and box will be open for comment.